# Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) not working on Android API 21 devices

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-5.0-lollipop

I have implemented Firebase on my native android app. Token is getting generated for API 21 and above devices. But I am not able to receive push messages (using data payload) on API 21 devices but working fine with API above 21.

What might be the root cause for this typical issue on API 21 / Lollipop Device? Any help is really appreciated...

Comment: What's the code that doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: Firebase integration successful and able to receive push messages on above API 21 devices. But push messages not received on API 21 devices (Lollipop Devices) though token is getting generated.